# id not returning from ExecuteNonQuery();

Tags: c#, asp.net, vsto

In here  i need to create a DataTable,But it doesn't return a id.There's no error.Actually here i provide a email address(epost).and i need to return id from database.

Coding Part Goes Here.

```
public string GetAllMails()
    {
        DataConnection dc = new DataConnection();

        string e="";
        int uid=-1,sid=0;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id");
        dt.Columns.Add("uid");
        dt.Columns.Add("email");

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace oNS;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolder;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Explorer oExp;

        oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        oNS = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        oExp = oFolder.GetExplorer(false);
        oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items items = oFolder.Items;

        SqlConnection conn = dc.SqlConnection;
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetDetailsByEmail", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail in items)
        {
            if (mail.UnRead == true)
            {
                e=mail.SenderEmailAddress;

               // param   <-- add sql parameters
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@epost",e));

                uid = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //send to db and take the id (uid)

                //if returned id
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

                row["id"] = sid;
                sid++;

                row["uid"] = uid;// uid

                row["email"] = e;

                dt.Rows.Add(row);

            }
        }

        return e;
    }
```

Stored Procedure goes here

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetDetailsByEmail]

@epost nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
Select Medlems_ID,[E-post]
from dbo.Members
where [E-post] = @epost
END
```

When i edit my coding,uid is a int.

```
uid = cmd.ExecuteReader(); or uid = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // it shows me conversion error.here i put as a comment
```

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` is for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE... not for a SELECT statement. Use ExecuteReader() instead

Comment: If your query always returns one value, you can use [`ExcecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Comment: now i change it like this uid = cmd.ExecuteReader(); then it gives me error " Cannot implicitly convert type system.data.sqlclient.sqlreader to 'int'"

Comment: @HenkMollema when  use cmd.ExecuteScalar(); it shows me this error Cannot implicitly convert type object to int and explicit conversions exist"

Comment: Try `Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) you will see the line:

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

You need to use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) to do what you want.

EDIT:

Here is how your code could look based on your comment. It is a bit strange that your sproc returns 2 columns but you are only interested in 1. Also it is not clear if you expect multiple rows or not.

```
if (dc.SqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open) 
    dc.SqlConnection.Open();

using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetDetailsByEmail", dc.SqlConnection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail in items)
    {
        if (mail.UnRead)
        {
            e = mail.SenderEmailAddress;

            //this is a little nasty
            if (cmd.Parameters.Count > 0)
                cmd.Parameters.RemoveAt(0);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@epost", e);

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    uid = reader.GetInt32(0);

                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["id"] = sid;
                    sid++;
                    row["uid"] = uid;// uid
                    row["email"] = e;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: now i change it like this  uid = cmd.ExecuteReader();  then it gives me error " Cannot implicitly convert type system.data.sqlclient.sqlreader to 'int'"

Comment: @JehanPerera I have updated my answer with some some sample code based on your code. I'm sure you can fix any minor issues with it or rewrite it to suit your own preferences.

Comment: thanks for the code.thats correct..But Onething. when loops run 1st item getting without issue.when moved it to second item it stops with executereader line with this exception "Procedure or function has too many arguments specified"